# Adding a nuget package to fsproj file through forge

Tags: .net, f#

[Forge](https://github.com/fsprojects/Forge) provides `paket install` subcommand through paket integration but invoking something like `paket install DotLiquid` does not add the package to `.fsproj` file(s).

Is there a way to make this happen, or is it expected that users would have to manually add the dll locations to `.fsproj`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have hands-on experience, but [it seems](https://github.com/fsprojects/Forge/blob/master/src/Forge/Commands.fs#L875) Forge is passing all arguments to Paket, so all the [Paket CLI](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-add.html) commands should be available.

In your instace try running `forge paket add nuget DotLiquid project "path\to\your.fsproj"`, but then I don't really see the advantage of running Paket via Forge as opposed to running it directly.

Comment: "I don't really see the advantage of running Paket via Forge" -- well, `forge paket` is one character shorter than `.paket/paket`, which is the usual way to call paket :) It's also available when you're starting a project and haven't run `paket init` yet. But if you have put `paket` in your PATH then yeah it's not very useful.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I didn't think of the "pre-init" case :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the dependency to paket.references and running `paket install` through forge adds the package to the corresponding fsproj file.